# I am having trouble creating a listner in Oracle 19C. Some help will be appreciated

Tags: oracle, listener, oracle-19c, tnsnames

These are my active services:

```
SQL> SELECT NAME FROM V$ACTIVE_SERVICES;

NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------

pdb3
orcldb
pdb2
pdb1
```

and this is my listener.ora config file:

```
    [oracle@oracle admin]$ cat listener.ora
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )


ORCLDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST = oracle)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcldb)
    )
  )
```

This is my tnsnames.ora file:

```
[oracle@oracle admin]$ cat tnsnames.ora
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle)(PORT = 1521))


ORCLDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcldb)
    )
  )
```

I am gettting this error after lsnrctl stop and start commands:

```
[oracle@oracle admin]$ lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 04-SEP-2023 20:38:41

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/oracle/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oracle)(PORT=1521)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                04-SEP-2023 20:38:41
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/oracle/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oracle)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

Once I connect orcldb, i will then move forward to pdbs. Can someone help me figure out what the problem is?

Comment: I can't see any trouble. Your listener was started successfully. Eventually the database will register in the listener provided its configuration is correct.

Comment: This might have changed in more recent versions, but it used to be the case that PDBs /did not/ get started automatically.  Each database [normally] registers itself with the listener but only once it gets started.

Comment: @BalazsPapp, you were right, it registered after a little while. Thanks!